# NFA random generator

Tags: finite-automata, pseudo-random-generators, randomness

I'm working on a NFA to DFA conversion tool that is different from the Subset Construction and I need to test this tool.

In order to be sure that the immplementation has no bug I'd like to generate a random NFA with these properties:

- The NFA should be connected
- The NFA should have one initial state and one or more final states
- The NFA should have ε-moves

Is there a known algorithm or a paper that explains how to generate this NFA automaton as random as possible?

Comment: Related: [What is a good algorithm for generating random DFAs?](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/12943/what-is-a-good-algorithm-for-generating-random-dfas)

Comment: First, you have to fix the alphabet. But a real difficulty is to give a precise definition of "as random as possible". For instance, do you consider isomorphic NFA (obtained by permuting the states) as distinct ones? If you want a uniform distribution, which parameter do you consider: number of states, number of transitions?